# How do I add all of a scanner's input to a string?

Tags: java, input

What I want is to be able to enter a string into the console and have it inputted into a string (an array would be fine, I just want to store it). Here's my example code:

```
System.out.println("What is your opinion?");
        while(user_input.hasNext()){
            choice = choice + " " + user_input.next();
        }
        this.opinion = choice;
```

All this does is ask for user input repeatedly. Thank you in advance for any input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want [`nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29):

```
System.out.println("What is your opinion?");
this.opinion = user_input.nextLine();
```

Note that you should follow Java naming conventions as well: `userInput`.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("What is your opinion?");

  Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
  String line = user_input.nextLine();
  String choice = "";
  while (!line.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")){ // here you can have terminate string. I used -1
     choice += "," + line; 
     line = user_input.nextLine();
  }
  System.out.println(choice);
```

Then you can get a string array by

```
String[] words = choice.split(",");
```